# how to subtract circle from an arbitrary polygon

Tags: math, polygon, subtraction

Given an arbitary polygon with vertices stored in either clockwise/counterclockwise fashion (depicted as a black rectangle in the diagram), I need to be able to subtract an arbitrary number of circles (in red on the diagram) from that polygon. Removing a circle could possibly split the polygon into two seperate polygons (as depicted by the second line in the diagram).

I'm not sure where to start.

[Example http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/89a0276d9d.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?89a0276d9d.jpg)

Comment: After the disk is removed, that's no longer a "polygon".

Comment: But what form of output do you want?  An approximation of the resulting shape with vertices, or equations of the curves?

Comment: need an appromixation of vertices

Comment: A circle or other ellipsoid has an infinite number of vertices, though.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: getting code to do this absolutely right is tricky. (Conceptually it's fine, but you can quickly get bogged down in numerical errors and edge cases.) You're basically asking for a 2D version of [Constructive Solid Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry). You might want to see if you can use an existing library written by an expert in computational geometry. There are some libraries [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/last/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#part_VI) that will probably do what you want, but you'll have to choose a representation that suits you best and convert what you have into that representation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a freeware polygon clipping library (written in Delphi and C++) that does what you're asking: http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/